# orderBy and OneToMany-Relation -- criteria query with jpa 2.0

Tags: sql-order-by, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have the following structure...

```
Entity A
  - ...
  - Collection<B> c (@OneToMany)

Entity B
  - ...
  - Date d
```

I want the queryResult to be ordered by the Date d via an orderBy-Statement in my criteriaQuery. How can I achieve this?

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> cq = cb.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> r = cq.from(A.class);
cq.select(r);

// orderBy-Statement -> cq.orderBy(cb.desc(r.get("c.d")).as(Date.class)));
// Error: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [c.d] against path

List<A> l = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Is it possible to have the ordering in the query?
If not, i'm supposed to write a method for ordering my resultList afterwards, right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, all in all I wasn't able to figure out how to use the orderBy-Statement I want. But Now I'm satisfied with an alternative approach (and in my opinion an even better one!):

1. Fetching the needed data from the database (unordered)
2. creating a datamodel and using it in the GUI
3. doing the sorting/ordering on the datamodel/GUI

By the way: I'm using the Primefaces.org-framework. Saves me a lot of work^^

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(r.get("c").get("d")));
```